# Group by database query in laravel not working

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel.

I have a database **table named A** and **column names are 1,2,3** .

In column 3 i have different values like a,b,c. Now what i want is to print out the total no of values of a,b and c using group by clause. Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance.

i am doing it like

```
$cot=DB::table('A')->group By('3')->count();

    echo $cot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a space in the query.

It should look like the below.

```
$cot = DB::table('A')->groupBy('3')->count();

echo $cot;
```